# Код выдает ошибку Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 99 at MinMax.main(MinMax.java:19)

Tags: java, массивы

```
public class MinMax {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int nums[] = new int[10];
        int min, max;

        nums[0] = 99;
        nums[1] = -10;
        nums[2] = 100123;
        nums[3] = 18;
        nums[4] = -978;
        nums[5] = 5623;
        nums[6] = 463;
        nums[7] = -9;
        nums[8] = 287;
        nums[9] = 49;
        min = max = nums[0];
        for (int i : nums) {
            if (nums[i] < min) min = nums[i];

            if (nums[i] > max) max = nums[i];
        }
        System.out.println(min + max);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for (int i : nums)` работает не совсем так, как вы его используете. В нём i будет поочерёдно присваиваться значения массива, т.е. на первой [итерации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) i = 99, на второй i = -10 и д.т.

Синтаксис `nums[i]` означает, что мы смотрим `i`-ый элемент массива.
Получается, что при таком цикле `for` на первой [итерации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) переменная `i` будет 99 и у вас происходит обращение к 99-му элементу массива (nums[99], но памяти выделено только для 10 элементов (массивы начинаются с нуля, значит при 10 элементах значения в квадратных скобках могут быть от 0 до 9 включительно, и 99 не вписывается в этот диапазон -> выход за пределы массива, что является ошибкой).

Чтобы использовать этот вариант `for`, достаточно заменить `nums[i]` на `i`, потому что при обычном цикле `for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)` поочерёдное обращение к элементам массива происходит через `nums[i]`, а при `for (int i : nums)` как я уже написал выше, `i` как раз поочерёдно и становится значениями элементов данного массива.

---

```
for (int i : nums) {
    // тело цикла
}
```

Как бы раскрывается в нечто подобное:

```
for (int k = 0; k < nums.length; k++){
    int i = nums[k];
    // тело цикла, но k скрыта и недоступна, доступна только i, а тело цикла начинается строго после int i = nums[k];
}
```

Comment: У меня задание в книге Шилдта переписать класс использую цикл foreach, "for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)" в таком виде он и был изначально.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Не обьясните ли мне почему происходит выход за границы массива и почему надо заменять nums [i] на i ?

Comment: Попытался расписать более подробно, надеюсь теперь будет понятно